# virt-manager: Remove mouse integration

Tags: debian, virtual-machine, kvm, libvirt, virt-manager

Host: Debian Bullseye
Guest: Windows XP
virt-manager: 3.2.0
Hypervisor: KVM
Emulator: /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64

I am trying to play an old Windows game in a virtual machine (because it won't work on Wine), but I am having problems with the mouse. Once inside the game, mouse movement in the VM is out of sync, or at least it overexaggerates my mouse movements.

My solution is to use USB redirection to pass the USB mouse directly to the VM. It works well, but I believe mouse integration is causing some interference.

The biggest issue, the Windows mouse cursor no longer follows my mouse movements - though the actual movements and clicks are registered, I can't see where I am clicking. Presumably it's still attached to the device corresponding to mouse integration. Also the windows cursor is visible even within the game.

Is there a way to remove the Mouse integration from the VM settings; I can see it as `PS/2 Mouse`, but the remove button is greyed out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Host mouse pointer not aligned with guest mouse pointer in Qemu VNC](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/555082/host-mouse-pointer-not-aligned-with-guest-mouse-pointer-in-qemu-vnc)

Comment: I tried adding a tablet as suggested in the answers to that question and it made no difference... I do think redirecting the mouse is the best solution, the only issue is the visible pointer in the guest seems to still be synced to the pointer in the host, but the clicks and movement are working as they should. Removing host-guest mouse integration is the only thing I can think of that may solve that. Is there no way to do it?